# Custom function runs in staging deployment slot, but fails in production slot

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure environment that was running under an outdated .NET version. I've updated my Function project accordingly, published to a staging deployment slot, and accepted the Azure notification asking if the destination could be updated to the correct runtime version. After publishing to the staging deployment slot the function seems to work fine. Clicking the function's URL redirects me to a page stating that the function is running properly. However, when I swap the staging and production deployment slots, the function no longer runs and I see the following error message in the function's Overview tab:

[image]

When looking at the production function's Configuration tab I see that after the swap the Runtime version is still set to "custom (~2.0)" instead of "~4" like it is in the staging function. Apparently, when I publish from Visual Studio to the Azure staging deployment slot it deploys all dependencies and properly updates the Runtime version, but this isn't happening during a swap. My question is: can I simply change this Runtime version directly in the Azure function configuration or will this break other things? I'm worried that if I change it and something goes seriously wrong then I won't be able to revert back (hence my desire to use deployment slots). Or is there a way to ensure that all dependencies/configurations are considered when performing a swap?

Comment: deploy directly to the prod slot, this will ensure the runtimes are same

Comment: @AsitK That seems to have worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Paugh Glad the issue is resolved, Can you post the answer that worked for you by deploying the Function directly in Prod slot? This is for the benefit of SO community.

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Well....ultimately it only kind of worked. After deployment my function failed to start and the application went down.

Comment: @Paugh :( sorry if i caused the trouble

Comment: Can you share the application error or the issue that failed the function to stop?

Comment: @AsitK Not your fault :). There was something different in the Prod instance that was impacting my attempted framework upgrades via deployment.

Comment: @SiddheshDesai The error was regarding a missing method in the EventHubClient. I did some framework checks/updates, rebuilt the class, and redeployed it. It seems to be working now but I'm monitoring expected vs incoming events since now Azure likes to perform resets which impact partition leases and function restarts.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/monitor-event-hubs?tabs=AzureDiagnostics%2CAzureDiagnosticsforRuntimeAudit%2CAzureDiagnosticsforAppMetrics Refer this to monitor Azure event hub events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the framework in both the core function class and dependent classes, rebuilt, republished directly to the Prod Deployment Slot, and stopped the function in the Stage Slot (I think resource sharing between the two was contributing to the issue even though they should be operating independently). The function is now functioning correctly.